# The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual C# solution with multiple projects.I referenced some projects in others.
For example I reference project named "Entity" in my main project.

I added Entity as a reference of my project.

Both of them use .Net Framework 4.0. (I tried others too)

I tried changing Any cpu to x86 and x64 in debug mode for both.

I have public class in Entity project and I add "using Entity;" to my main project.

All of the projects build successfully.

I tried removing and adding Entity from references.

I can run the project in localhost but when I copy the project files on server and run if over there it shows this error (line 11 is red):

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error
```

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Entity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 9:  using System.Collections;
Line 10: using Microsoft.SharePoint;
Line 11: using Entity;
Line 12:
```

I searched a lot but still nothing..
I would appreciate it if you could help
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In

```
using Entity;
```

Entity is a namespace, not a project. Replace Entity in this line with the namespace you used in your project.